# java.net.URI resolve against only query string

Tags: java, uri

I'm trying to build URI's using the JDK [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). 
I want to append to an absolute URI object, a query (in String). In example:

```java
URI base = new URI("http://example.com/something/more/long");
String queryString = "query=http://local:282/rand&action=aaaa";
URI query = new URI(null, null, null, queryString, null);
URI result = base.resolve(query);
```

Theory (or what I think) is that resolve should return:

```
http://example.com/something/more/long?query=http://local:282/rand&action=aaaa
```

But what I got is:

```
 http://example.com/something/more/?query=http://local:282/rand&action=aaaa
```

Why [#resolve()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.net.URI%29) "eats" the last path? If the new URI (`query`) is built as:

```
URI query = new URI(null, null, base.getPath(), queryString, null);
```

It works well.

Comment: check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to respond myself. Javadoc really explains correctly. As [URI#resolve()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.net.URI%29) says, in section 3.b.:

> Otherwise the given URI's path is relative, and so the new URI's path
>   is computed by resolving the path of the given URI against the path of
>   this URI. This is done by concatenating all but the last segment of
>   this URI's path, if any, with the given URI's path and then
>   normalizing the result as if by invoking the normalize method.

So.... I didn't read correctly. Should I delete this response? Or let it responsed by myself?

Comment: The documentation is clear, but what is the motivation. Why remove the last segment?

Comment: This is clearly against the WHATWG URL spec: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#relative-state , unfortunately there was a bug report on this issue: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6519518 and the resolution is "Won't fix", because - legacy.

Comment: I created a bug report against the `URI` class here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8218962 , There's no community commenting feature for Oracle's bug tracking system, but at least we can track progress on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

**First Case:**

```
base = http://example.com/something/more/long
```

and `query` evaluates to be

```
query = ?query=http://local:282/rand&action=aaaa.
```

According to the documentation of method  `public URI resolve(URI uri)` , it resolves the query URI against the base URI. While resolving if the method finds a path in the query URI, it assigns the same path to the new resolved URI. In this case there is no path associated with the `query`. If you see the below snippet of the `resolve()` function, it will get more clear.

//snippet

```
 String cp = (child.path == null) ? "" : child.path;
        if ((cp.length() > 0) && (cp.charAt(0) == '/')) {
        // 5.2 (5): Child path is absolute
        ru.path = child.path;
        } else {
        // 5.2 (6): Resolve relative path
        ru.path = resolvePath(base.path, cp, base.isAbsolute());
        }
```

where cp is the child(in your case query path). As its null here, the flow goes into the else loop where the resolved query is a assigned a path from the base URI.

Your new URI has this path `/something/more/`, as it strips everything after the last "/" character.

**Second Case:**

base = http://example.com/something/more/long
and `query` evaluates to be

```
query = /something/more/long?query=http://local:282/rand&action=aaaa
```

Here it goes to the if loop which assigns the query path to the new URI's path. Path of your query URI is `/something/more/long` here i.e it includes the "long" value as well. May be this is how they resolve the URI's. Look through the documentation you will have a more clear idea of it.