# Are query parameters allowed in opaque URIs?

Tags: java, uri, query-string

Java's [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#isOpaque--) class defines opaque URIs as follows (emphasis mine).

> A URI is opaque if, and only if, it is absolute and its scheme-specific part does not begin with a slash character ('/'). An opaque URI has a scheme, a scheme-specific part, and possibly a fragment; **all other components are undefined**.

True to the documentation, an opaque URI returns `null` for a query param.

```
URI uri = URI.create("stackoverflow:foo?key=value#frag");
uri.isOpaque() == true
uri.getScheme() == stackoverflow
uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() == foo?key=value
uri.getQuery() == null
uri.getFragment() == frag
```

Is this behavior specific to Java's URI implementation, or does the URI spec disallow query params in opaque URIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `URI` class is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) as conforming to [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and  [RFC 2732](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt):

> Aside from some minor deviations noted below, an instance of this class represents a URI reference as defined by RFC 2396: Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax, amended by RFC 2732: Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URLs.

*Section 3. URI Syntactic Components* doesn't specifically *disallow* query components in *opaque* URIs, rather it simply *doesn't define* a syntax for them.  An opaque URI, by definition, requires scheme-specific knowledge to know *if* there is something analogous to a query component and exactly *how* to parse it.  It is completely legal to have one, but it cannot be supported in the general sense (under this RFC) without that special knowledge. The relevant RFC text is:

> The URI syntax is dependent upon the scheme.  In general, absolute
> URI are written as follows:
>
> ```
> <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
> ```
>
> An absolute URI contains the name of the scheme being used (`<scheme>`)
> followed by a colon (":") and then a string (the `<scheme-specific-part>`)
> whose interpretation depends on the scheme.

Only the *generic syntax* provides an RFC-defined query component, and that syntax requires at least one slash (`/`) immediately following the first colon(`:`) after the scheme.

> The URI syntax does not require that the scheme-specific-part have
> any general structure or set of semantics which is common among all
> URI.  However, a subset of URI do share a common syntax for
> representing hierarchical relationships within the namespace.  This
> "generic URI" syntax consists of a sequence of four main components:
>
> ```
> <scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>
> ```
>
> each of which, except `<scheme>`, may be absent from a particular URI.
> For example, some URI schemes do not allow an `<authority>` component,
> and others do not use a `<query>` component.
>
> ```
> absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )
>
> ...
>
> hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]
> net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]>
> abs_path      = "/"  path_segments
> ```

Both of the aforementioned RFCs have been [obsoleted by RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), but for [backwards-compatibility](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6791060) reasons Java's existing API and behavior is [unlikely to be changed](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/net-dev/2014-July/008588.html).

The URI implementation varies from the newer RFC not only in how it defines valid components of the URI, but also *behaviorally*.  For example, see:

- [Is Java's URI.resolve incompatible with RFC 3986 when the relative URI contains an empty path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22203111/2390644)

A quick search turns up at least one open-source [library](https://github.com/dmfs/uri-toolkit) attempting to provide an RFC 3986-compatible implementation, but the previous link is neither an endorsement nor recommendation.  Compatibility with existing `java.net.URI`-based APIs may be limited.