# UriComponentsBuilder truncates with custom scheme

Tags: java, spring

I am using `UriComponentsBuilder` as such:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("com.stuff.mycompany:auth/stream/service");
allRequestParams.forEach((k, v) -> builder.queryParam(k, v)); // add all query params
URI uri = builder.encode().build().toUri();
```

When I run this code, it returns `com.stuff.mycompany:?query=whatever`, and it truncates the `auth/stream/service`. I noticed that if I add two slashes after the colon, it works as expected (`com.stuff.mycompany:auth/stream/service`).

However, I have a requirement to follow and cannot include the double slashes. How can I get this working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. When you parse that string with `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString` the builder internals looks like this:

```
scheme = "com.stuff.mycompany"
ssp = "auth/stream/service"
```

Here SSP is a scheme-specific part. Take a look at `queryParam`:

```
public UriComponentsBuilder queryParam(String name, Object... values) {
    Assert.notNull(name, "Name must not be null");
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(values)) {
        for (Object value : values) {
            String valueAsString = (value != null ? value.toString() : null);
            this.queryParams.add(name, valueAsString);
        }
    }
    else {
        this.queryParams.add(name, null);
    }
    resetSchemeSpecificPart(); //Here is where you lose your SSP
    return this;
}
```

Looks like Spring / Java implementation of URI [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50263219/750510) 100% RFC-compatibel and it does not support queries on opaque URLs. Consider using [other implementations](https://github.com/dmfs/uri-toolkit).