# Load image from java src resource folder in xslt for display in pdf

Tags: image, xslt

Hello I need to load images from the src/main/resources/images folder to a pdf using xslt version 1.1

I have tried the following but doesnt display the image in pdf:

```
<fo:block text-align="center">
    <fo:external-graphic src="classpath:images/logo.png"/>
</fo:block>
```

I am not sure what i do wrong can someone guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving resources from the classpath by a "classpath:" URL isn't supported by default in Java. If you are not using a framework or library which supports classpath URLs, you can add support for them by implementing and registering a [URLStreamHandlerProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/spi/URLStreamHandlerProvider.html) for the "classpath" protocol.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088592/91822) for an example implementation, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76857673/91822) for a slightly modified version which supports using a leading slash in the path, enabling the resolving of relative URL references.